# Подключения UnityEngine.Android

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Как можно подключить либо импортировать в проект UnityEngine.Android, в офф. манула есть несколько тем, и там эти библиотеки подключены, искал я, но так и не нашел как её включить в проект.

P.S. SDK и NDK установлены.

Comment: А не могли бы вы ссылку приложить на офф мануал, о котором вы говорите? я нашёл только вот это https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-API.html и ни класса там такого, ни пространства имен я не вижу

Comment: @M.Green вот в предыдущей темы проскакивало, и сам захотел научиться - https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/android-RequestingPermissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное пространство имён появилось с Unity 2018.3. Обновите приложение до новой версии и установите расширение для Android, которое можно выбрать при установке Unity. Либо в запущенном приложении в окне BuildSettings нужно выбрать вкладку Android и нажать кнопку скачать.

После этого вы сможете использовать данное пространство имён и его классы в своём проекте.

Comment: у меня 2018.2 14f1 - если обновлюсь могут слететь настройки проектов?

Comment: @k0vpack, скорее всего нет, там всё с обратной совместимостью)